# Adding proxy to Antminer S3

Tags: proxy

Is it possible to add a proxy to an Antmner S3? I want to place the Antminer at work, but there is a proxy I have to go through. I can see where to put the DNS information, but not where to put a proxy name. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to place the Antminer at work

Using your employer's electricity for personal gain is likely to get you into some trouble. If you have a legitimate reason to consider such a setup (for example, if your employer pays a lower, business electricity rate than you do), you can ask your employer for permission.

> I can see where to put the DNS information, but not where to put a proxy name

If you need to go through a restrictive firewall, you can try a project such as the [OnionPi](https://learn.adafruit.com/onion-pi/overview) (Adafruit), which uses a Raspberry Pi (35$) to tunnel all incoming connections through Tor. You will need to change the Wi-Fi antenna in the original project with a USB to Ethernet adapter, as the Antminer needs to connect via Ethernet, and besides, running a Wi-Fi router inside your company's network will get you into trouble.

Tor itself can connect through a proxy with the `HTTPProxy` and `HTTPProxyAuthenticator` configuration directives. If entry nodes are on the firewall's blacklist, you can use the [BridgeDB](https://bridges.torproject.org/) to get some circumvention servers that use encryption and obfuscation to evade blacklisting.